# Access values from a dict in a function called in a Jinja expression

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm passing a dict from a Flask view to a Jinja template.  I can render the values in the dict, but if I try to pass them to `url_for` I get `UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute 'eId'`.  Why did the second access fail when the first succeeded?

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        cur = g.db.execute('select title, text, id from entries1 WHERE userid = ? OR public = 1 order by id desc', [userInfo['userid']])
    else:
        cur = g.db.execute('select title, text, id from entries1 WHERE public = 1 order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1], eId=row[2]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

```html
{% for entry in entries %}
    This works: {{ entry.eId }}
    This errors: {{ url_for('delete_entry', btnId=entry.eId) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What type is eId?  Have you tried {{ url_for( 'delete_entry', btnId=str(entry.eId) ) }}

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `"{{ url_for('delete_entry', btnId= entry.eId) }}"` you should have `"{{ url_for('delete_entry', btnId= entry['eId']) }}"` because elements in a dictionary should be accessed by their `get` method. The only reason that `{{ entry.title }}` works is because of jinja2.

Essenially `{{ entry.title }}` gets evaluated by jinja whereas `"{{ url_for('delete_entry', btnId= entry.eId) }}"` gets evaluated by python and breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `entry` is a dictionary. While Jinja's expression syntax allows you to use attribute syntax (`dict.attr`) for dictionaries, as soon as you're passing an argument to a function with Python syntax you need to use Python's normal dictionary access syntax, `dict['attr']`.