# Difference between an item and an attribute - Jinja, Python

Tags: python, attributes, jinja2, items

I am reading about [templates in Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/), especially about variables. I would like to ask you for explanation for this sentence about acessing values of the passed to Jinja syntax objects:

> Implementation
>
> For the sake of convenience, foo.bar in Jinja2 does the following
>   things on the Python layer:
>
> - **check for an *attribute* called bar on foo (getattr(foo, 'bar'))**
> - if there is not, **check for an *item* 'bar' in foo
>     (foo.__getitem__('bar'))**
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.
>
> foo['bar'] works mostly the same with a small difference in sequence:
>
> - **check for an *item* 'bar' in foo. (foo.__getitem__('bar'))**
> - if there is not, **check for an *attribute* called bar on foo.
>     (getattr(foo, 'bar'))**
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.
>
> This is important if an object has an item and attribute with the same
>   name. Additionally, the attr() filter only looks up attributes.

**What is the difference between an item and an attribute?**

PS  - If it's relevant: I work on dictionaries. I have just read that [Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090767/access-values-from-a-dict-in-a-function-called-in-a-jinja-expression) enables to access the value with the key as an attribute (dict.key), however I feel confused after reading this part about the order of the processes. The comparison "key-value" pair makes understing the part above more challenging.

Answer (score 3):

In python classes **instances** have *attributes*; dictionaries contain **items**.
In a `dict` an item is a combination of a key and a value

```
a = object()
a.attribute = 'value'
b = dict()
b['key'] = 'value'
b.items()
```

Comment: Jinja treats dictionaries as class instances, thus we can access their attributes. Firstly, Jinja checks whether the object is an... object and has an attribute - a key. If we use Python layer and dic['key'] syntax, in the beginning we look for dictionary's items. The case I have described is the matter of the priority for Python and Jinja, whether they process an item or an attribute. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Attributes describes the objects of the class, whereas items are the key-value pairs present in the dictionaries.

The way of accessing these also matches with its priority rules:
1. Attributes of objects are accessed with '.' operator.
2. Key-Value pairs of dictionaries are accessed using **getitem** or '[]' operator.